# Find the value of $(\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\pi \cos x}{x})^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The value of $(\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\pi\cos x}{x})^2dx$ is less than

(A) $\frac{3}{2}$

(B) 2

(C) $\frac{5}{2}$

(D) 3

I have no idea of solving this type of integration problem but I tried the following steps after removing the definite terms  $\int\frac{\pi cosx}{x}dx=\frac{\pi sinx}{x}+\int\frac{\pi sinx}{x^2}dx$ after this step not able to proceed . The answer of this problem is all options ABCD are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Turn the integral in the post into a double integral

$$\int_\pi^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}\:dx = \int_\pi^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy}\cos x\:dy\:dx$$

then swap the order of integration

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{y\:e^{-\pi y}}{y^2+1}\:dy$$

Since $y < y^2 + 1$ we get that the integral

$$0 < \int_0^\infty \frac{y\:e^{-\pi y}}{y^2+1}\:dy < \int_0^\infty e^{-\pi y}\:dy = \frac{1}{\pi}$$

which is less than all of the answer choices.